branch.io link opening browser instead of app, flutter
I'm having problems with with branch.io in flutter android.
I integrated the flutter branch sdk, setup everything, validation passes.
In the validation log there is an example link and I also created a link in the dashboard.
I paste both links into the notes app.
When I press the validation link my app opens but the payload says it's not a branch link.
When I press the link I created it doesn't open my app and goes to the fallback website BUT after that if I open the app manually the link payload is passed to me in the listener.
I tried opening the link from inside the app with url_launcher. Same behavior.
I'm at a loss at what I'm supposed to do. All this was done in a completely new and clean flutter app with only the branch sdk present.

Branchster Here. After reviewing the problem with given details. Mostly this type of issue is caused by improper implementation of the intent filter.
try adding your app link in your intent filter.
<!-- Branch App Links - Live App -->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- REPLACE `android:host` with your `app.link` domain -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.app.link" />
            <!-- REPLACE `android:host` with your `-alternate` domain (required for proper functioning of App Links and Deepviews) -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example-alternate.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>

Please refer to the documentation below for implementing the intent filter in the code.
Link: https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration#4-configure-app
I hope this might solve your issue. if you are still facing issue. Please contact support@branch.io to investigate the issue further.
Thank you
